# How to make WordPress urls matching static html urls

Tags: urls

I have a website currently running in WordPress, before that site was static html, I converted that in WordPress.

Now problem is I don't want to loose links, Google ranking, etc.

I want the same link (as on my old site HTML site) for pages (in WP) but WordPress generate its own slug.

Even I try to use pretty permalink plugin but no benefit.

For example old event page link: `http://example.com/events/events.htm`

WP new event page link: `http://example.com/events/`

I want link same as on old site (this is my goal don't want to loose old links)

Second example, old history page link: `http://example.com/History/history.htm`

Here you will notice "History" H is caps

WP new history page link: `http://example.com/history/`

Please provide your suggestion that help me to make links same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like every "old" URL is a bit different from each other so you should manually create permanent redirects (HTTP 301) for each URL. I recommend using either [Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirects/) (very simple and intuitive) or [Safe Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/) (more advanced features) plugins.